# Extracting a variable from a function call in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to extract strings in Python received by a function.

Consider the following;

I have a script that runs in Python. The script runs continuosly. It binds to a USB port and listens for incoming ZigBee data frames.

I have a function that dissassembles this dataframe;

```
    # Decoded data frame to use later on
def decodeReceivedFrame(data):
           source_addr_long = toHex(data['source_addr_long'])
           source_addr = toHex(data['source_addr'])
           id = data['id']
           rf_data = data['rf_data']
           #samples = data['samples']
           return [source_addr_long, source_addr, id, rf_data]
```

When I print this function later on; it gives me the correct incoming values. For example;

```
decodedData = decodeReceivedFrame(data)
print decodedData
```

Output:

```
[None, None, 'rx', '<=>\x80\x02#387239766#XBEE#126#STR:wm2 #STR:c47cb3f57365#']
```

What I want to do, is to extract the two STR variables of this string. This means the wm2 String, and the c47cb3f57365 string, in two seperate variables.

Which function in Python would be the most efficient to solve this situation?

Comment: is it always in the same format?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The two STR entries can be different at will. However, the displaying format will be the same.

Comment: are they always numbers and letters?

Comment: To clarify: yes. The first STR will always be wm[number] and the second STR shows a MAC-address of a embedded XBee chip

Comment: so STR can appear anywhere in the string  not just at the  end and start?

Comment: Sorry if unclear; the STR -notations- will always be at the same place, in the same order of the output. However, the content, such as wm2 and c47cb3f57365, can be different.

Comment: I added an answer based on the strings always being in the same format, it is as efficient as you are likely to get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

presuming the data is always in  the format as discussed in the comments, this would be one of the most efficient ways:

```
s =  '<=>\x80\x02#387239766#XBEE#126#STR:wm2 #STR:c47cb3f57365#'
# rsplit with 2 as the second arg will split twice on #STR starting from the send of s
spl = s.rsplit("#STR:",2)
# get last two elements from spl 
a,b = spl[1],spl[2][:-1] # ,[:-1] removes the final #
print a,b
wm2  c47cb3f57365
```

Some timings using ipython and timeit:

```
In [6]: timeit  re.findall(r'STR:(\w+)', s)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 µs per loop

In [7]: %%timeit
spl = s.rsplit("#STR:",2)
a,b = spl[1],spl[2][:-1]
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 409 ns per loop
```

If you were to use a regex you should compile:

```
patt = re.compile(r'STR:(\w+)')
patt.findall(s)
```

Which improves the efficiency:

```
In [6]: timeit patt.findall(s)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 945 ns per loop
```

Comment: Seems messy just dumping the content of your interactive session with hardly any comment. Which one was actually better? Looks like the `s.rsplit("#STR2",2)` took less than 1/4th as long, to me, but you don't really make that clear in your answer.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, the timings are literally there to see, how can it be any more transparent?

Comment: What's the gibberish on lines 2 through 5 of your answer? Why do you have IPython prompts mixed into your answer? Why is `timeit` mixed in with the code doing the actual work? You've made 6 edits to this post already - it seems to me you must know it can be better. How much was the speed up when you started compiling the regex?

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting approach! However, I get the following error applying your theory;  spl = decodedData.rsplit("#STR:",2)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Comment: @MichaelP, you should be splitting the string, so either do that before you add i.e   rf_data and add a and b to your list  or do the operations on  last element  of your returned  list.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, do you actually know python, timeit ipython etc..?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, it seems to me you must know how to do it better; please show us, I'm actually interested in the answer too

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I recognize the fact that you're using IPython without you mentioning it anywhere in your answer; what does that tell you about my understanding? I'm not asking because I don't understand - I'm asking because I can easily imagine others not understanding. I would suggest replacing your non-standard IPython prompts with standard Python prompts (or just doing away with the prompts altogether) so that a Python novice can more easily follow the answer.

Comment: @StefanSchouten: I know how to format it better and am trying to encourage others to have equally easy to read answers. I can't think of any better methods than what is already included in this answer.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Right, I am trying to apply the operations to the last items of my list. However, I think I'm overlooking something. Is the approach as simple as just specifying the list entry integer numbers? Could you maybe add a example of splitting such string?

Comment: @MichaelP,  yes, I presume `rf_data` is what you want to split yes?

Comment: Yes, rf_data is what contains the STR entries.

Comment: @MichaelP, then in the context of your list, consider s to be element 3 of your list so  `decodeReceivedFrame(data)[3]`

Comment: Perfect! I understand your approach and I get the proper results now. Appreciate you taking the time for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re    
>>> re.findall(r'STR:(\w+)', '<=>\x80\x02#387239766#XBEE#126#STR:wm2 #STR:c47cb3f57365#')
['wm2', 'c47cb3f57365']
```